# Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_34: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm inputting a 2D array of (822222, 2) into this model:

```
regressor = Sequential()                                                      

regressor.add (LSTM  (2, activation = 'sigmoid', dropout = .1))
regressor.add (Dense (2, activation = 'tanh'))                  
regressor.compile (optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

regressor.fit (x = document, y = document, batch_size = 32, epochs = 1000)
```

but this returns an error on the last line, only accepting an array with `ndim = 3`:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_34: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

I tried reshaping, but most configurations I come up with make the data unusable. What would make the model accept my inputs?